# converting JSON object in R to string representation gives \" rather than ". How to get rid of slash?

Tags: json, r, tostring

I need to get ride of the forward slash when converting a JSON object to a string. Why do I get \" rather than the double quote, and how can I show as just a double quote with the slash? Consider the example, d_json without slash, but slash appears when converted to string:

```
library(jsonlite)
d = data.frame(one=as.factor(c('a','a','b','b','c','c')),
           two=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

d_json <- toJSON(d)
d_json
##[{"one":"a","two":1},{"one":"a","two":2},{"one":"b","two":3},{"one":"b","two":4},{"one":"c","two":5},{"one":"c","two":6}] 

toString(d_json)
##[1] "[{\"one\":\"a\",\"two\":1},{\"one\":\"a\",\"two\":2},{\"one\":\"b\",\"two\":3},{\"one\":\"b\",\"two\":4},{\"one\":\"c\",\"two\":5},{\"one\":\"c\",\"two\":6}]"
```

Comment: try doing `cat(toString(d_json))` or writing the result of `toString(d_json)` to a file. Those slashes aren't there, they are just being quoted for the display. Also, `d_json` is _already_ a character vector. No need to use `toString()`.

Comment: Thanks hrbrmstr, cat works to print correctly, but would actually like to get a string object that I can pass, or even modify if needed. class(d_json) shows "j_son" not "character". I appreciate your help, but need something else to get the "character" format!

Comment: no, no you don't. `d_json` is _already_ a character vector (i.e. a "string") after toe `toJSON()` call. Please study the base R data types and `jsonlite` documentation a bit more thoroughly. I've written (literally) a dozen pkgs that use this to `POST` to APIs. You're doing something else wrong. You should also consider posting a different example since the real trouble you're having is working with your API.

Comment: hrbrmstr, I think you're right. I'm using the plumber package and the result I am returning has \". I will continue to investigate, and see if I need to post a refined example. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The slashes in the output you're seeing are just escape characters, and `\"` will count as one character. Check out `str_sub(toString(d_json),3,3)` and `str_sub(toString(d_json),4,4)` to see this effect on further string operations. As mentioned in hrbrmstr's comment, cat() shows how the final string will look when actually displayed.

Comment: Thanks hedgedandlevered, I'm trying to pass a string using an API call, and in the terminal the \" is still showing up when I call the API. The example is different from the toy example above, but same issue with the \" showing up rather than just the double quotes. I would like to get rid of is possible, any suggestions?

Comment: well when you're calling the API and looking at the result in the terminal, you're still looking at a string, right? R will display that with the escape characters. try `cat()` on the result of the API call.

Comment: I tried CAT and the result is that the string only prints in the console, and nothing passes through to the terminal window.

Comment: Not sure I understand, what is the "terminal" vs the "console"? Are we talking about R in both cases?

Comment: No sorry, R console vs. Mac Terminal.